# What does it mean when i write String line = ""

Tags: java

I have seen in a program a declaration like

```
String line = ""
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
```

what does it mean ?
Please clarify .

Comment: What is the type of reader?

Comment: You really need to learn the basics there guy

Comment: @BitNinja file reader

Comment: If the `reader` is of `BufferedReader`, check out this [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine())

Comment: @wns349 I want to know about String line=""

Comment: This is very basic. People should know this much at least to ask instead of asking such question here.

Comment: Next time, be more specific about what part/parts you don't understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that the string is initialized as an empty string firstly. To use a variable, we should give it an initial value and this is called initializing the variable. Otherwise the compiler will throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

First,

```
String line = "";
```

Creates a new line variable with the value of empty string, you could also use,

```
String line; // or = null;
```

Because,

```
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
  System.out.println(line);
}
```

Begins a while loop replacing the String referred to by `line` with a new line obtained by calling `readLine()` from `reader`). Next, if that String is null the loop body would not run (if it isn't the loop body does). Finally, I added a loop body. In this case to print the `line` to the console, which again only prints *while* `line` is not null.

Comment: Thank u @Ellot I got Your point

Answer (score 0):

For loop implementation of the same,

```
for(String line = reader.readLine(); line != null; line = reader.readLine()){
   System.out.println(line);
}
```

This make it easy to understand.

Comment: It calls `readLine()` twice before allowing the user to actually use `line` the first time you enter this loop

Comment: @VinceEmigh No it doesn't. The second `line = reader.readline()` assignment only happens *between* loop iterations.

Comment: @VinceEmigh I think u are wrong.. It doesn't.

Comment: @Boann You're right, i'm sorry. I forgot the second assignment won't happen til after the iteration

Comment: I don't like the code duplication in here.  If you don't like constructs like `while (line = reader.readLine()) != null)`, an alternative that doesn't rely on code duplication is to use `while(true)` and `break`.

Answer (score 0):

It means read text file line by line till the eof with BufferedReader

Answer (score 0):

`String line` declares a variable named `line` of type `String`.

`= ""` initializes the variable with an empty string. That value is not used and is replaced immediately afterwards by the loop, so the `= ""` is an unnecessary bit of superstitious coding which should be removed.

In either case, there needs to be a `;` at the end of it.